# CSS inconsistencies between Chrome and IE9 even with the meyer reset?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, webfonts

**On the left is Chrome and on the right is IE9.**

[image]

As you can see with the image above, even with the *Meyer CSS Reset* there are yet inconsistencies between browsers. Two examples in this image:

1. IE9 clearly has a darker font for just about all text.
2. For whatever reason, the `<hr/>` tags aren't lining up (but they sure are close) and that throws off the rest of the content.

Is there something more I need to do, other than applying the *Meyer CSS Reset* to get some more consistency between these browsers?

Additionally, with the content you see above, other than colors and font sizes, there are no margins or padding applied after the reset.

#### CSS

```
h1 {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #154995;
}

h2 {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333333;
}

h3 {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #154995;
}

h4 {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333333;
}

h5 {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333333;
}

.small-text {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: regular;
    color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the css reset you use. A css reset, as the name says, resets only the basic default values of the browser. But you can;t change the way a browser renders elements.

Comment: @Kyle, I'll keep that in mind and keep my bolding and stuff to a minimum a bit more. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences you point out are all based on the fact that two different fonts are being used in your chrome and IE9 outputs. Once you tweak the css `font-family` so both browsers use the same font then it should be ok.

**UPDATE:**
After seeing your css, you're specifying only `Lato` font for your elements, it seems both chrome and IE9 can't find the font `Lato` so both are applying a default font, which is different from one to another, try specifying fallback fonts like:

```
font-family: Lato, Arial, sans-serif;
```

If above still give you different outputs then `Lato` is being picked in one browser and not other, you can check that by using:

```
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
```

for all your elements and see the output is the same on both browsers.

**UPDATE 2:**
Also see instructions on how to add a Lato webfont to your website: 
http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Lato

Comment: Please see my edit and help guide me if you can - I don't yet fully understand what you're saying but I'm sure seeing the CSS will help you.

Comment: Alright, so if `Lato` is the required font, how in the world do I apply a web font like that?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helped me out and that solved those issues!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link with instructions on how to add a Lato webfont to your page.

Comment: Stackoverflow had a bug with recognizing the link, I've fixed the link now, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

According to me `font-family` you are using is probably not a system font, it's a web font so what's the thing here is 1 browser is taking up the web font and other is not, so the default `Times New Roman` font is used